# Web3.py: 'intrinsic gas too low', how to select gasPrice and gas?

Tags: gas, web3.py, gas-price, gas-limit

In [previous question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/124545/gas-gwei-not-working-intrinsic-gas-too-low) on the forum this issue was already discussed, but it does not address another one: how to select `gas` and `gasPrice` so that you wouldn't bet all wallet's money and transaction would go through?

I am trying to make test transaction from my wallet to another. I use following code:

```
tx = {
    'nonce': nonce,
    'to': recipient_address,
    'value': node_connector.to_wei(0.001, 'ether'),
    'gas': 300000,
    'gasPrice': node_connector.to_wei(40, 'gwei'),
    'chainId': 42161
}

signed_tx = node_connector.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key)

tx_hash = node_connector.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
```

I tried different combinations of `gas` and `gasPrice`, but it either gives me the error brought up in linked question (`ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'intrinsic gas too low'}`) even when I use `gas=200000`(200k) or error, that I don't have sufficient funds:
`ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address xxxx have 10000000000000000 want 13000000000000000'}` (I have 18,5 dollars on the wallet)

How should I get sensible values for `gas` and `gasPrice`? I tried remove `gas` as was suggested, but it is obligatory parameter.